# Cannot delete folder as root

Tags: command-line, permissions

The folder structure is: `/home/bobuser/ftp/files`

I am logged in as root, and have taken ownership of `/bobuser`, `/ftp` and `/files`. I have 777 permissions on all folders. There is nothing inside `/files`.

When I'm inside `/files` and do `ls -a` I get

```
. ..
```

When I do

```
lsof +D /home/bobuser/ftp/files
```

I get this:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    1479 root  cwd    DIR  253,1     4096 256003 /home/bobuser/ftp/files
lsof    2080 root  cwd    DIR  253,1     4096 256003 /home/bobuser/ftp/files
lsof    2081 root  cwd    DIR  253,1     4096 256003 /home/bobuser/ftp/files
```

If I try to kill service 2080 or 2081 (`kill -9 2081`) it tells me service doesn't exist. Those two PID numbers change every time I run the same command. If I kill 1479 it kills my SSH session as user and I'm logged out.

In fact I want to delete `/bobuser` and everything below.

**EDIT:**

More output as requested by comments:

Logged in with root user and changed directory to root, even though I was there already.

```
root@myhost:~# cd /root
```

Running this next line returns nothing. I only get a response if I'm cd'ed into the files directory, then I get the output as posted above.

```
root@myhost:~# lsof +D /home/bobuser/ftp/files
```

Tried this line next and return is 0

```
root@myhost:~# ls -l /home/bobuser/ftp/files
total 0
```

Comment: Is that a typo? kill -9 2091 should be kill -9 2081. Is bobuser a user on your system? If so: you can use `deluser --remove-home bobuser` to remove both the user and its home.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yea sorry it's a typo I've tried the right pid but like I said it keeps changing and telling me process doesn't exist. And I've already deleted the user, but cannot get rid of his home directory.

Comment: By `FD = cwd` it seems to me that you are in that directory, run: `cd /root; rm -rf /home/bobuser/ftp/files`,

Comment: @Amir: change your directory to `/root`, then run `lsof +D /your-path` again. add the output to your question.

Comment: @Amir: Now that `lsof` produce nothing, what is the `rm` command output? still device busy?

Comment: @Ravexina still no go. I still have the console open and just ran these commands in succession. root@myhost:~# rm -rf bobuser
root@myhost:~# rm -r /home/bobuser/ftp/files
rm: cannot remove '/home/bobuser/ftp/files': Device or resource busy

Comment: @Amir: Do you get any output for `mount | grep -i bobuser/ftp`?

Comment: @Ravexina i get /dev/vda1 on /home/bobuser/ftp/files type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

Comment: @Amir: okay, we found the problem. just before doing anything, run `lsblk` add the output to your question, I will add an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56803/discussion-between-amir-and-ravexina).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer:

```
umount /home/bobuser/ftp/files
rm -r /home/bobuser/ftp/files
```

If you take a look at the **FD** section of `lsof` man page, you will find out that `cwd` means current working directory.

The other thing you mentioned is different PIDs for 2nd and 3rd lines. Those are the PIDs of `lsof` command, so every time you run `lsof`, it will run with a new PID and then it will be closed.

After changing your directory to `/root`, we can see that there is no open file under `/home/uerbob/ftp/files` directory, so my first guess is that some partition is mounted there.

You should run below command to see if any partitions are mounted there:

```
mount | grep -i bobuser/ftp
```

If yes, you will get an output like this:

```
/dev/vda1 on /home/bobuser/ftp/files type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Then simply unmount the partition and remove the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the folder is not mounted, so the `umount` command will not work.

I have used for this kind of undeletable folders this command as user not even root:

```
sudo rm -r /mnt/hdd/movies/folder-problem
```